# при повторном подключении к API (которое меняется раз минуту) показывает устаревшее значение

Tags: ios, swift, api

Собственно есть кнопка, которая подключается к API (которое изменяется раз в минуту):

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer "+token!]
        Alamofire.request("http://app", method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            print("response",response)
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                let success = json["success"].boolValue
                print("successs",success)
                if success == false{
                    let error = json["error"].stringValue
                    print(error)
                }else{
                    for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["data"][0] {
                        let name = subJson["user"]["name"].stringValue
                        self.nameCheck.append(name)   
                    }
                    print("PresentTitle",self.nameCheck[0],"\(Date())")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

И дальше происходят не совсем понятные для меня вещи, когда я клацаю на кнопку я вижу правильное, нужное мне значение, потом жду минуту(чтобы изменились данные в `API`), повторно клацаю кнопку и вижу одно и то же устаревшее значение, самое первое. Вот тут `print("PresentTitle",self.nameCheck[0],"\(Date())")` я вижу дату текущую, но значение-устаревшее.

Но если я перезайду во `ViewController` с моей кнопкой и нажму её, опять появляется нужное мне значение, но только при первом подключении, хотя `API`  регулярно меняется, информация релевантна только один раз.

Собственно подскажите в чем проблема, и почему оно так работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всегда запрашиваете 0-вой элемент массива. При перезаходе данные обнуляются и `self.nameCheck[0]` будет то что вам нужно, при повторном запросе `self.nameCheck.append(name)` данные запишутся в 1вую ячейку. И ее уже надо будет доставать из `self.nameCheck[1]`.

Решением может быть или обнулять массив(непонятно тогда зачем массив, можно просто создать переменную), или брать последний элемент `nameCheck.last` только он опциональный и нужна проверка на пустоту.

```
print("PresentTitle", nameCheck.last ?? "nil","\(Date())")
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли.